# How to exclude assembly from NuGet package when packing csproj?

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget

I want to use "dotnet pack" to produce a nuget package, but I don't want to include the assembly file. My project doesn't have code, yet calling "dotnet pack" creates a package with an empty assembly in it.

How can I do this using csproj and dotnet.exe?

Answer (score 23):

You have two options:

1. Use a nuspec file instead of csproj. NuGet's support for packs a csproj is not as flexible as using the nuspec directly. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package#create-the-nuspec-package-manifest-file
2. In your csproj file, set the property `<IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput>` (add to a PropertyGroup section). This instructs the "Pack" target not to add the assembly to the package. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/msbuild-targets for more details.

Comment: How does the usage look like for IncludeBuildOutput if you want to exclude only some files?

Comment: Note, you can combine the second approach with `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.Build.NoTargets/1.0.26"/>` to avoid building the empty assembly in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately, `IncludeBuildOutput` seems to be evaluated only once, rather than once per target framework. Any idea how to exclude build output for a specific TFM? I want this TFM in my package, but with an empty lib folder.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque you can probably use `<IncludeBuildOutput Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' != 'net46' ">true</IncludeBuildOutput>` or something similar if you're trying to exclude builds for specific frameworks and not others

Comment: @ThomasLevesque scratch that lol, after rereading your comment when struggling with this again, I see that you note that it's only evaluated once instead of per-tfm. Alas, it would be nice to have a good answer to this.